# Viewpager with Tablayout not working proper

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Here i am getting result like...

1. Activity start..

   at at that time these two fragments calls 
    -> Fragment 1 load
    -> Fragment 2 load in background
2. swapping right (means going from frag 1 to fragment 2)

   at that time I am in fragment two and same time
    -> Fragment  3 load in background
3. swapping in right (means going from Frag 2 to 3 then)

   --> there is nothing issue.

**HERE IS MY CODE**

Main Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is my adapter class

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
   // add fragment 
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
    // for title
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

And there is 3 fragment right now there is nothing into that fragment .....

Comment: Are you having problems with Fragments losing data when tab is changed? Sorry, couldn't get your question properly.

Comment: i mean that when fragment one load at same time fragment two OnCreateView also load... and same way.. when i am going to fragment 2 then fragment 3 onCreateView call

Comment: So what's the issue? It's a normal VIewPager behaviour to load the next fragment.

Comment: then how to achieve it with fragments ????

i want horizontal scrolling facility ..nd change fragments on scroll

Comment: "ViewPagerAdapter always load the next fragment instead of the current" is this your problem

Comment: Your question is still not clear to me. Please update your question with relevant details.

Comment: viewpager always loads the next fragment

Comment: so there is any solution ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewPager setOffscreenPageLimit default is 1

Please view this link
[Visit Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

**Update**
Please Override this method of fragment

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {

        // load data here
    }else{
        // fragment is no longer visible
    }
}
```

Comment: @RjzSatvara Why are you set only current fragment loaded at a time ?

Comment: because fargment 2 have some services which are calls. and i want to call that only when fragment 2 is call or load

Comment: Please override setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) method of fragment

Comment: I have test demo and check condition isVisibleToUser its work for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this tutorial..this may helps you

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

you need not include this lines in your onCreate Method **(Remove this lines)**

```
 viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
 viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

By default,Viewpager will set '0' for starting index..

Comment: not working , fragment 2 is also load with fragment 1

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this. This runs well on my app :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    assert tabLayout != null;
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.setSelected(true);
}
```

And no need to add **viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);**

Because by default ViewPager will be set to the Starting index of 0. As already told by Ajay Jayendran.

Hope this will works. (:

Comment: when Activity start Fragment 1 and Fragment 2 also load... instead of loading only fragment 1.

Comment: Yes Your and My Both have a same code..There is no issue in your Code....You set ViewPage width & height match_parent in XML..???

Comment: then i think that is the Problem of in your Fragment...now you have to Put all your code..without that we can not solve your Problem dear..

Comment: there is nothing in Fragment... only OnCreateView with Log.e("","").

Comment: try to Use Your all Fragment with imports this

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

and also viewPager is :

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

Comment: now my Final thinking is...My VIewPagerAdapter is on my  TabMainActivity.try to use VIewPagerAdapter class in your  Main Activity of Tabs.instead of Unique adapter class